# Copy Security for HTML site

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax, security

I just finished my first Site Template on ThemeForest. 
Now i searched for some tips to shared it to get the most purchased. Then i found some programmes which allow you to copy a full site from a web, e.g [HTTrack](http://www.httrack.com/) 

Now my question is: how can i **prevent a copy request** by a program like HTTrack? 
Maybe i can manipulate something in my Demo-Files to confuse the program... 

I found nothing in the web...

Comment: Do note, HTTrack only alows copies of the output, not the source of your site - it will parse html and javascript for links if its not able to see the links it wont copy them, so, it wont succeed in "post"ing variables, nor, manipulating flash/silverlight screens

Comment: You can pars the site at your own pace e.g with firebug or something. And i'm sure, somewhere out there are programs which copy everything.

and i don't use flash/silverlight in my themes. i only use HTML(5), CSS(3) &jQuery... 
What do you mean with "post"ing variables? 
So call the site over PHP with post?

Comment: Nothing can read the source from the server (eg php,asp etc) unless they physically can access the server - if they can, then change your hoster.  html can be retrieved in 1 of 2 ways, post or get, post is used usually with forms.. httrack cant follow that as it cant set values in a form.  You asked how to stop it copying, flash/silveright can help with that as programs like httrack cant test the code within, and work with the responses in the same way

Comment: +1 for the complexe comments. 
sad, sad. then i hope, not many persons copy my theme :)
thanks for help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to protect your intellectual property, add a (c) to it.

If you publish on the web, there nothing else you can do.

If you don't want others to copy your theme, don't publish it. And don't fall for stupid tricks like disabling the right mouse button. It only annoys people and will stop nobody.

One possible solution is to place only screenshots of your theme online, not the actual CSS/HTML, but if I were a potential buyer I wouldn't buy based on a screenshot. I would like to test it in the wild on different browsers/OS's.

Comment: All of the Themes on ThemeForest is protected with the copyright. 

I must not upload the original file for the demo...?
For example the site flickr. When you want to save a image per right-click, it shows the copyright term... It isn't possible to realise this for a HTML site?

or protect the full Site around with PHP or Frames or what ever...?

Yes, Screenshots are ugly. i won't this...

Comment: If it is public, it can be saved.

Comment: @dTDesign: What epascarello said. :-)

Comment: @dTDesign: I am not sure if it is sad, but each to his/her own opinion. :-) I am a big fan of open internet, and free sharing of ideas and material. The internet is ideal for that, but sadly for you, it is hard to protect stuff (other than claiming you made it first). If somebody "steals" it, you can always try to proof that you made it, but it is a hard road, with lots of countries having different rules.

Comment: Sure, i love the free internet! For the free stuff ;).

And what is when i insert a js which send me all month all the information of the site. So when i become more than one (my demo) information, i know it was copy...? Is it legally?

Comment: Is it legal to use some piece of .js you copied from some place? If it was published under a friendly licence it is (read here for example: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gpl). But it is very very hard for a technical minded person to understand all possible legal situations that can arise in all countries in the world. I know I gave up and almost exclusively use FOSS (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FOSS). If you are interested, I advise you to start with Richard Stallman: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stallman, the real under appreciated here of Free Software.